# Windows GUI Control: Difference between LVCOLUMN and HDITEM?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am using Windows List-View control and am little bit confused by LVCOLUMN and HDITEM, former structure is used to define column properties, latter is used to define actural header object of the column, do I understand correctly?

If so, do I need to create / define both?

Answer (score 1):

You usually just deal with LVCOLUMN and let the listview itself update the header control for you.

You generally only need to use HDITEM (or talk to the header control at all) when accessing the header directly, which is rare (but does happen in some situations).

Comment: I run into this question when I try to use filtering feature of List-View control in report mode. LVCOLUMN and HDITEM have some identical properties, like text, width and order. If I InsertColumn() already, do I need to InsertItem for Header, or just SetItem for Header to change it?

Comment: @Sheen, InsertItem on the listview should automatically update the header. Think of the header as an internal child/component of the listview. Generally, the only time you need to access the header directly is if you want to do something that the listview itself doesn't provide a method for. If the listview does have a method then it will generally update the header itself; you don't usually need to keep the two things in sync yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand if I call InsertColumn(), header item will be automatically created. And if I want to enable filter and LPARAM features I have to call GetHeaderCtrl().SetItem() to specify HDI_FILTER and HDI_LPARAM.

Comment: @Sheen, It's a while since I've used filtering but that sounds right, yeah.